# Responsive/fluid/mobile optimized site: Top attribute on absolute element - can it "scale"

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project that is rather time sensitive. The task is to make a micro site that users can access through their smartphones, where they will be able to access a number of movies. They will scan a QR code (I know they are dead, I didn't plan the campaign). and land on this site. I am not a fontender, but know my way around html + css and I have been able to find a few things around the internet, but now I've come to a dead end. I am optimizing the site for max-width 640px with a 100% scalable width down to min-width of 320px. I've gotten it all working quite well on my test site, implemented fonts etc. but I run into a problem when I am trying to place the div #textbox inside the #sunny div, on top of the #image div. I have managed to center the #textbox, but I can't get it to align vertically and "stay" vertically aligned no matter what size screen the user views the page at.

Here is my code and css:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN"
"http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div id="sunny">
            <div id="image">
                <img src="images/1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div id="textbox">
                <p>Jacket Name</p>
                <a href="http://www.google.com">See Details</a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
@font-face { font-family: FuturaStdBook; src: url('../fonts/FuturaStd-Book.otf'); } 
@font-face { font-family: FuturaStdBook; font-weight: bold; src: url('../fonts/FuturaStd-Bold.otf'); }

#container
{
    background: #fff;
    font-family: FuturaStdBook, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    max-width:640px;
    min-width:320px;    
    margin:0 auto;
}

#header
{
    padding: 20px;
}

#logo 
{
    width:33%;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}

#sunny
{
    width: 100%;
    max-width:640px;
    min-width:320px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

#textbox  {
    background-color:white;
    width:33%;
    left:33%;
    top:30px;
    min-width: 70px;
    height:50px;
    text-align: center; 
    z-index:1;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    color:#a3a3a3;
}

#textbox p {
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:0;
}

#textbox a {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#666666;
}

#image {
    width:100%
    position: absolute;
}

#image img{
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

N.B: Please bare in mind that I need to repeat the code, and have like 7 or 8 "identical" areas under each other, so the CSS have to be applicable to this design.

Hope someone is able to help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its a case of using too many divs. What you need to do is to place your elements in a div with position:relative, and then position the elements themselves as position:absolute and go about positioning them as you'd like.

Comment: But I don't want to position them as I like, I want them to position themselves according to the screen size of the viewer, that is the whole point.